# Difference between CrudRepository and RedisTemplate's HashOperations

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis

So, I started learning Redis and I am using Spring Boot Data Redis as shown in this [article](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Using-Redis-with-CrudRepository-in-Spring-Boot). When I call the `findAll` method of `UserRepository` it returns all the `User`s saved via the `save` method of `UserRepository` but when I use the `HashOperations` object to get all the Hashes it returns only the `User` hashes which are put into redis via the `HashOperations` object. I am creating the `HashOperations` object in the `UserController` (API) as shown below.

```
private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

private HashOperations<String, Long, Order> hashOperations;

public UserController(final UserService userService, final RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
    this.userService = userService;
    this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    this.hashOperations = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
}
```

So, I want to know what the difference is or why does it return different results when I call the `hashOperations.entries("users")` and `userService .findAll()`

Comment: This does not answer your question directly, but Redis is both very useful and terribly idiosyncratic. I personally do not recommend using repository-type abstractions on top of it if any sort of interoperability is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

The repository will store the values differently.
The default is something like user:key
you can find it in Spring docs.
while Hash operations will store it inside the address you gave it in the method.